# A Stochastic Limiting Inequality Proof

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, inequality, stochastic-processes

Let $(X_p)_{p\ge 0}$ be a sequence of non-negative random variables with finite mean for each $p\ge 0$. Then 
$$\liminf_{p\to\infty} X_p^{\frac{1}{p}}\le \liminf_{p\to\infty}E(X_p)^{\frac{1}{p}}$$
almost surely.

This is a lemma in a paper I am reading, specifically Lemma 3.2. of http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~mike/papers/parallel-shifts.pdf. I am a little miffed at the motivation of the proof. I would like to see what alternative proofs there are and hopefully understand what could inspire a proof for this kind of propositions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this qualifies for an alternative proof anyway, define 
$$A_j:=\left \{ \liminf_p X_p^{ 1/p}\geqslant \liminf_p\left(\mathbb E[X_p]\right)^{1/p} +\frac 1j\right\}.$$
We have to prove that for each $j$, $\mathbb P(A_j)=0$. If not, then by Markov's inequality and Fatou's lemma, 
$$\liminf_p\left(\mathbb E[X_p]\right)^{1/p} +\frac 1j\leqslant 
\frac 1{\mathbb P(A_j)}\int_{A_j}\liminf_pX_p^{ 1/p}\mathrm d\mathbb P 
\leqslant \liminf_p\int_{A_j}X_p^{ 1/p}\frac {\mathrm d\mathbb P}{\mathbb P(A_j)} .$$
Since the map $t\mapsto t^{1/p} $ is concave and $\mathrm d\mathbb P/\mathbb P(A_j)$ is a probability measure, we obtain 
$$\liminf_p\left(\mathbb E[X_p]\right)^{1/p} +\frac 1j\leqslant \liminf_p\left(\int_{A_j}X_p\frac {\mathrm d\mathbb P}{\mathbb P(A_j)}\right)^{ 1/p}\leqslant \liminf_p\left(\int_{\Omega}X_p\frac {\mathrm d\mathbb P}{\mathbb P(A_j)}\right)^{ 1/p}=\frac{\liminf\limits_p\left(\mathbb E[X_p]\right)^{1/p}}{\liminf\limits_p\mathbb P(A_j)^{1/p}}=\liminf_p\left(\mathbb E[X_p]\right)^{1/p},
$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: If we define $A:=\left \{ \liminf_p X_p^{ 1/p}>\liminf_p\left(\mathbb E[X_p]\right)^{1/p}\right\}$, we should get $\liminf_p\left(\mathbb E[X_p]\right)^{1/p} <
\frac 1{\mathbb P(A_j)}\displaystyle\int_{A_j}\liminf_pX_p^{ 1/p}\mathrm d\mathbb P$. Then the inequality is strict for the last line without $\frac 1j$ and the argument goes through. This way we do not have to test the inequality for each natural number $j$. Do you agree?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I had a look into the paper and the first thing to notice is that it is easy to proof that $E(X)<=x$.

So let us first do that and see what happens:

Define (just like in the paper) : $X=\lim \inf_{p \rightarrow \infty} X_p^{\frac{1}{p}}, x= \lim \inf_{p \rightarrow \infty} E(X_p)^{\frac{1}{p}}$ and notice that Fatou's Lemma states that $E(X) \leq E(\lim \inf_{p \rightarrow \infty} X_p^{\frac{1}{p}} \leq \lim \inf_{p \rightarrow \infty} E(X_p)^{\frac{1}{p}} = x (=E(x))$.

So that means that $E(X-x) \leq 0$.
But that is not enough for convergence P-almost surely.

So now consider when something converges P-almost surely.

We want to proof that : $P(X \leq x)=1$. One of the ways to do that is by considering the space where $X >x$. So we actually want to show that the measure of this space becomes $0$.

That is a difficult statement, so let us consider the expectation of our variable $X-x$. We are then sure that $E((X-x) \mathbb{1}_{X>x}) \geq 0$, cause we only count positive values then.

The important thing is to write down $\lim \inf_{p \rightarrow \infty} E(X_p^{\frac{1}{p}} \mathbb{1}_{X>x})$ and notice that
 they are not independent, so we have to split them and we can do that by using Holder's inequality, which says that

$\lim \inf_{p \rightarrow \infty} E(X_p^{\frac{1}{p}} \mathbb{1}_{X>x}) \leq x E(\mathbb{1}_{X>x})^{1-\frac{1}{p}}$.

Now the arguments are split and the rest is solvable.

Comment: I understand the proof in the paper, but I want to understand the motivation. There is a leap between "we are sure that ..., because we only count positive values there" and the following paragraph. How does the latter come about from the former paragraph?

Answer (score 0):

This looks a lot like Fatou's lemma: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma
Maybe by defining f_p =X_p^(1/p) and letting \mu be the Lebesgue measure, you can already obtain the result.

Comment: Yes, indeed. But as Fatou's Lemma calls for an integral (expectation) on the left hand side, how do you get to the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, we define $(\Omega, \sigma-\text{algebra}, P)$ as a probability space and here we define $(X_p)_{p \geq 0}$ on that space with $(X_p)\geq 0$. We write then $E(X_p) = \displaystyle\int_\Omega X_p dP$. Now define $Y_p:=X_p^{1/p}$. 
So the usual statement of Fatou's Lemma becomes then 
$E(\liminf Y_p)\le\liminf E(Y_p)$.

Now note that the difference here is that the question require you to say something about the convergence in mean. So define again $Z_p=\liminf Y_p$ and the statement then becomes $Z_p\le E(Z_p)$ in $P$-a.s.

Now note that you have a non-negative r.v. with finite mean, thereby this can be shown (the space where the distance is more than $\epsilon$ has measure $0$).

Comment: You should consolidate your answers into one piece. You can always edit your previous one by clicking on the edit button. You should also put $ sign around the math symbols so as to make it into LaTeX format. Otherwise it is really hard to read.

Comment: How do you get $Z_p \le E(Z_p)$ in P a.s.? I doubt this is correct

Comment: Thanks for the updated version, I am new here, so that is why I didn't understand the way to write these things down. Can you maybe send the paper?

Comment: Fatou's Lemma is indeed used in the paper. A clever restriction in the probability space with the characteristic (indicator) function together with Holder's Inequality produces the result. Lemma 3.2. of http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~mike/papers/parallel-shifts.pdf is the proposition and proof in concern. Your mention of Fatou's Lemma being similar to the proposition does give me a clue as to what motivates the proof. I would like to hear more regarding the trick they use if there is more. If there are alternative proofs, it would be even better.

Comment: You are welcome. Welcome to math.stachexchange.com.